# Can't toggle fn+esc on Linux on Asus X412

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, asus

I have an Asus X412 and I've been trying to get my function-key shortcuts working on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04). As I see it, the UEFI allows me to select two states for the function keys:

1. **Enable by default:** Where in the boot-up state is to use the original <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> buttons.
2. **Disable by default:** Where in the boot-up state is to use the hotkeys.

<kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> will then allow you to toggle it for the duration of your runtime for both states.

In my case, (1) works but I cannot use <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> to toggle the hotkeys. I have to keep using the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>FX</kbd> keys to use them. As for (2), when I boot up, it's always toggled by default - i.e., I have to use <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> to disable <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys and everything works fine.

Currently, I'm using (2) but I'm not sure how I can get it working to how I want it (boot up and get the hotkeys working by default).

I'm not sure I require the usage of the `acpi_oci=` boot arg to get this working but it didn't work when I tried it a few months ago.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the kernel module parameter of asus_wmi's `fnlock_default` to false. This made the brightness key work by default in my case, instead of being <kbd>F4</kbd>/<kbd>F5</kbd> keys.

For me this involved editing `/etc/default/grub`, and adding the parameter like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="asus_wmi.fnlock_default=0"
```

Then running

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

yields the desired behavior.

Source:

- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/platform/x86/asus-wmi.c#L52
- (asus_wmi is a built-in) https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html
- Own experience with my Asus Zenbook Duo UX8402